# Publish UTM from geoserver using mssql geometry

Tags: geoserver, sql-server, wgs84, utm

I have my world lat, lon coordinates insert in an ms sql *geometry* column like this:

```
geometry::Point(56.120417, 10.159337, 0);
```

I have an ms sql store in geoserver and a layer that exposes these coordinates.

My problem is integration with an existing system.. I am told my coordinates are exposed as WGS84, but they need them exposed in UTM

This seems trivial, but after two days searching and experimenting I am still unable to find a solution to expose my ms sql geometry coordinates from geoserver as UTM.

Comment: GeoServer will automatically reproject your data if the client requests them in another projection as a WMS layer. For a WFS dataset your client will receive them as WGS84 and should capable of reprojecting to any required projection. So I'm not sure what your problem is

Comment: Thanks..  To be honest..  Neither am I.. It's the client who is asking for this?

Comment: which client are you using? this should all be baked in

Comment: I have no idea..  With "client" I meant a corporate client. I am just exposing an endpoint from geoserver..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you query the data via `WFS` you need to specify the `srsname` parameter with the `EPSG Code`. Geoserver will automatically reproject.

For example to get your Layer in `EPSG:25832` - [UTM Zone 32N](https://epsg.io/25832)

```
https://DOMAIN/geoserver/WORKSPACE/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=WORKSPACE%3ALAYERNAME&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=application%2Fjson&srsname=EPSG:25832
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the feedback.  I have tried your suggestion : https://focuspect-wfs.azurewebsites.net/HedeDanmark/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=HedeDanmark%3AMarker&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=application%2Fjson&srsname=EPSG:25832, but the coordinates still show up as they where inserted in the db. Feel free to give it a go!   Am I missing a setting in geoserver? The "client" expects coordinates like this: 572250.4302418156,6227374.090475168

Comment: So it looks like either you defined the source CRS wrong because when I query https://focuspect-wfs.azurewebsites.net/HedeDanmark/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=HedeDanmark%3AMarker&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=application%2Fjson - it gives me coords that look like EPSG:4326 - (Lat/Lng) - but the WFS says they are in EPSG:25832. Or the geo column in your Database is already in EPSG:25832 but you inserted Lat/Lng.

Comment: Hi..  Thanks SO MUCH for the input..  I'm on it and will return..  I'll be back ;)

Comment: Hi Bernd.. Once again thx.. I will mark this as answer.. For some reason geoserver was locked to native EPSG:25832 and the declared was also EPSG:25832.. Changing the declared to EPSG:4326 as per your comment  fixed everything..  Now I'm trying to figure out why native was locked to EPSG:25832, but that's another question ;)..  Thx agaain!